# How to merge two faces of different normals to create a corner?

Tags: modeling

I want to merge the faces and make sure the vertices match up.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Had you tried to extrude some of the faces and try manually to fit with the other one without merging?, tried to recreate your model and merge but it looks like blender cannot do it, therefore, you could try to extrude one of the face and try to fit with the other, i hope this could be useful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install this [**Destructive Extrude** Addon](https://gumroad.com/l/cQjUX)

In Edit mode Select the Face and Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and select the Destructive Extrude option.

Now you can extrude and if need to snap to face press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

It never creates extra faces and no doubles.

[image]

Comment: In this way you leave two internal faces, which is wrong

Comment: yes, first delete the 2 faces

Comment: sorry correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't "Remove doubles" take care of the internal faces?

Comment: Also, thank you for answering. This solved my problem.

Comment: No, even with this edited "extrude face" version, an internal face is left, and "remove double" won't get rid of it. Delete the opposite face before extruding the other.

Comment: @m.ardito plz check the edited answer